# fprintf not printing new line

Tags: matlab, file-io, newline

I am trying to send an array that is [2 x N] doubles large to a text file using the `fprintf()` command. I am having problems in that `fprintf()` is not recognizing the new line command (`\n`) or the carriage return command (`\r`). The code I am using is

```
fid = fopen([Image.Dir,'CtlPts_',Image.Files{k},'.txt'],'w');
fprintf(fid,'%.4f\t%.4f\n',control_points{k});
fclose(fid);
```

where the data I am trying to print is in the cell `control_points{k}`.

The tab gets printed fine, but everything in the text file gets printed on one line, so this is why I am assuming that it is ignoring my new line character.

Is there something wrong with my syntax that I am not seeing?

Comment: have you done a dump of the file? I know that on many systems, \n is not enough to create what you're asking for (and so, maybe you have to do \r\n)

Comment: @KevinDTimm I am not sure what doing a dump of a file is (could you explain in an answer format) but using \r\n worked. Post this as an answer and I will select it.

Comment: the reason for the dump is to verify that the file actually contains the \n.  If it does (which is likely) then the second part of my comment / answer applies.

Comment: For others who come here: it often is because the number of `FormatString` specifiers (the `%--` bits in the line you're printing) are more than the number of numbers you give it to print. In such cases, newlines don't print.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know that on many systems, \n is not enough to create what you're asking for (and so, maybe you have to do \r\n)

Comment: `\r\n` really only applies to Windows, most other platforms use `\n`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - And yet, it appears that this was the solution to the problem

Answer (score 9):

An alternative solution is to [open](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html#inputarg_permission) the file in *text mode*, that way MATLAB automatically inserts a carriage return `\r` before any newline `\n` character in the output on Windows systems:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '%f\t%f\n', rand(10,2));
fclose(fid);
```

Note that this is somewhat unnecessary, since most editors (with the exception of Microsoft Notepad) recognize Unix/Mac/Windows line endings.