# Why does fprintf behave differently in text mode compared to a properly set carriage return in normal mode?

Tags: matlab, fopen, carriage-return, notepad, printf

The following question is more a curiosity than a problem.

I stumbled over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6536599/2605073), offering two different answers which seem to be equivalent. But they aren't, what made me thinking.

Imagine a `system` call which echoes two lines:

```
[~,message] = system( 'echo hello && echo world' );
```

returns:

```
hello
world
```

If one wants to write these lines to a `.txt`-file and open it in notepad, the common approach would be:

```
fid = fopen([pwd '\helloworld.txt'],'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', message);
fclose(fid);
winopen('helloworld.txt')
```

which returns

```
hello world
```

As notepad obviously is not able to recognize the line feed `\n` properly, the solution is to use `'wt'` instead of `'w'` to enforce text mode, which is supposed to be slow. return:

```
hello
world
```

The [documentation to fopen permissions](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) says:

> To open files in text mode, attach the letter 't' to the permission
>   argument, such as 'rt' or 'wt+'.
>
> On Windows® systems, in text mode:
>   -Read operations that encounter a carriage return followed by a newline character ('\r\n') remove the carriage return from the input.
>
> -Write operations insert a carriage return before any newline character
>   in the output.

So in my understanding it basically does:

```
fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n', message)
```

but the output again is:

```
hello world
```

What else does `'wt'`? How could one obtain the same behavior with `'w'`?
I'm sorry if this question is meaningless and trivial, but after some frustrating hours I'm just curious what I was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my understanding it does

```
fprintf(fid, '%s', strrep(message, sprintf('\n'), sprintf('\r\n'))
```

If you do

```
fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n', message)
```

you're only adding one carriage return and a newline at the very end of your message, which is after "world\n".The newline character between "hello" and "world" remains without carriage return.

So in your fprintf your message is `"hello\nworld\n\r\n"`, where it should be `"hello\r\nworld\r\n"`

You can check this by reading the output file in bytes, knowing that `\n` will be a `10` as `uint8` and `\r` a `13`:

```
>> fid = fopen('test.txt','wt');
>> fprintf(fid, 'hello\nworld\n');
>> fclose(fid);
>> fid = fopen('test.txt','r');
>> bytes = fread(fid, Inf, 'uint8')'

bytes =

   104   101   108   108   111    13    10   119   111   114   108   100    13    10
```

Comment: thanks for that detailed answer on that finally simple question!