# newlines not visible in notepad with MATLAB's fprintf

Tags: matlab, printf, notepad++, newline, notepad

I'm trying to append new lines to a `.txt` file in a loop with MATLAB as follows:

```
for i=1:N
    % do something
    % something done. write them to text file:
    fid = fopen(outfile, 'a');
    for j = 1:numel(smth.text)
        fprintf(fid, '\n%s;%d', smth.text{j}, smth.data(j));
    end
    fclose(fid);
end
```

when I'm finished, I open the file in Notepad++ (if relevant, the encoding is UTF-8) and see it correctly, i.e.:

```
text1;data1
text2;data2
etc
```

however, when I open the file in Windows' Notepad, I see it like this:

```
text1;data1text2;data2etc
```

so the line breaks are not showing up in Notepad.

How can I fix this so I can get the newlines everywhere?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: See also: [Why does fprintf behave differently in text mode compared to a properly set carriage return in normal mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298269/why-does-fprintf-behave-differently-in-text-mode-compared-to-a-properly-set-carr/)

Comment: See also: [fprintf not printing new line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536599/fprintf-not-printing-new-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `\r` in yoru `fprintf` command for windows Notepad to identify the line break (notepad++ display will not be affected).

```
for i=1:N
  % do something
  fid = fopen(outfile, 'a');
  for j = 1:numel(smth)
    fprintf(fid, '\r\n%s;%d', smth.text{j}, smth.data(j));
  end
  fclose(fid);
end
```

A good explanation for the difference between `\r` and `\n` can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/374028/how-are-n-and-r-handled-differently-on-linux-and-windows)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. However it's not working as expected; Notepad display is not changed (still no breaks), and in Notepad++ I get double breaks instead of single ones. **Edit**: when I change the order, i.e. make it `\r\n`, it works! Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes - I wrote the answer from memory without testing so I put them the wrong way - I will update